# Styling span:hover to make span element remain visible

Tags: html, css

I've set up span elements to be visible only when buttons are hovered over. I'd like the span to continue to be visible if the cursor is then moved onto the span element. (This already happens in Chrome by default.) I thought I could do that just with `span:hover {visibility: visible}`, but it doesn't work. Do I need to add something else as well, or is something else wrong?

reduced CSS:

```
.tooltipT {
  position: absolute;
}
.tooltipT span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.tooltipT:hover span, .tooltipT span:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 400px;
  }
.tooltipT:hover span, .tooltipT span:hover {
  bottom: 16px;
  left: -200px;
}
```

reduced HTML:

```
<div class="pix">
             <button class="tooltipT" style="top: 50%; left: 50%;">1
                    <span>blah
                    </span>
             </button>
            <img src="img/MIPs.jpg" alt="Melt-in-Place Station details">
</div>
```

It's live [here](http://moonwards.com/planning.html), the image with the span element involved is half-way down the page, it is used on the pink button in the middle.

I put it on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kimholder/pen/QNjarM) and am playing with suggested solutions there.

Comment: you should post your HTML in the question as well

Comment: is the goal keep the span visible after leave the button (while hovering the span)?

Comment: @freestock.tk Yes. The span is right against the button, so there is no moment when the cursor is off the button but not on the span. However that  isn't enough, it seems.

Comment: @freestock.tk But I don't want the span to then be always visible, it needs to disappear once the mouse moves off it.

Comment: gotcha. seems to be a firefox bug.

Comment: There seems to be two identical CSS hover selectors (.tooltipT:hover ...); one  defines visibility and width, the second defines position. Why not combine these attributes together in a single class selector? I suspect different browsers handle this condition in different ways. Hence the different results.

Comment: @JohnH There are two because in the actual CSS there are a bunch of different tooltip classes, each with its own positioning style. They are grouped and the visibility styling applied to all, the positioning style is unique for each one.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need JavaScript here because the minute you move off the button (to move towards the now visible span), the button is no longer being hovered and so the CSS class no longer applies. This should do it:

```
 button.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    span.setAttribute("class", "tooltip");
 });
```

Obviously, replace button with the id of your button and tooltip with the name of the class that should be applied when the button is moused over.

Comment: Won't the span then not disappear after that? Do i need to add a "mouseout" function as well?

Comment: The span will not disappear after this because you are saying that WHEN the button is moused over, the span should become visible. You are not saying "while" the button is being moused over, the span should be visible.

Comment: There is no need to use JQuery as all it will be doing is the addEventListener that I have provided.

Comment: Yes, the syntax of JQuery is just easier for me because I haven't done any kind of JS much at all. And I do want the span to disappear again when the mouse moves off it.

Comment: The code to remove the class is almost identical. span.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ span.setAttribute("class", "")});  Don't take this the wrong way, but if you don't know JS very well, you should not be using JQuery. Often JQuery makes code simpler, but it it really is nothing more than JavaScript wrappers that often slow things down.

Answer (score 2):

It does work if you let the span outside of the button. In this case you'll need the `element ~ element` or `element + element` selector to show up the span when hovering the button.

```css
body {
  background: honeydew;  
}

.tooltipT {
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: gold;
  border: 3px solid black;
  top: calc(40% - 40px);
  left: calc(50% + 40px);
}

span:hover, .tooltipT:hover ~ span {
  visibility: visible;
}

button {
  border: 3px solid black;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%; 
}

button:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="tooltipT">0</button>
<span>_blah</span>
```

Comment: Wow, that's neat. However I've been trying to get it to work with the complete code for the page, and it won't so far. In fact it does some weird things. I'll put up a Codepen so you can see if you like. The thing is, there are images with a bunch of these spans, so I need something that won't make all the spans visible when a button is hovered.

Comment: If you have more than 1 span, use the `+` selector instead of the `~` selector (or use ids or yet :nth-child(n)).

Comment: Codepen: http://codepen.io/kimholder/pen/QNjarM  - though I seem to have introduced a syntax error, I'm looking for it. It is doing the weird thing I said and I haven't even put in the fix you've suggested. W3C says element + element 'Selects all <p> elements that are placed immediately after <div> elements'.

Comment: so the difference is only the ability of `~` handle a 3rd object between them (and we need to be specific while working with multi objects). Thanks for the info!

Comment: [**then let it outside of the button as i said**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqvRGQ?editors=1100)

Comment: I am trying to set it up the way it will have to work on the real site. Let me work on that a while. I see your Codepen works great, but i continue to have trouble when i try to put it in with the stuff that has to be there. That class isn't unnecessary in the live site. To put the position styling similar to where you have it, i have to rewrite a dozen classes or so.

Comment: **Im reposting this comment to do not let a wrong information on the air:** `elementA ~ elementB` selects the **elementB** even if there is an **elementC** between them. But, if there is more than 1 **elementB** after it, them all will be selected, except if you be specific like using `id` or `:nth-child(n)`. `element + element` works in the same way but doesnt accepts an **elementC** between them.